# Accessing Mongo replicas in kubernetes cluster from AWS lambdas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-lambda

Some of my data is in Mongo replicas that are hosted in docker containers running in kubernetes cluster. I need to access this data from the AWS lambda that is running in the same VPC and subnet (as the kubernetes minions with mongo db). lambda as well as the kubernetes minions (hosting mongo containers) are run under the same security group. I am trying to connect using url "mongodb://mongo-rs-1-svc,mongo-rs-2-svc,mongo-rs-3-svc/res?replicaSet=mongo_rs" where mongo-rs-x-svc are three kubernetes services that enables access to the appropriate replicas. When I try to connect using this url, it fails to resolve the mongo replica url (e.g. mongo-rs-2-svc). Same URL works fine for my web service that is running in its own docker container in the same kubernetes cluster.

Here is the error I get from mongo client that I use...
{\"name\":\"MongoError\",\"message\":\"failed to connect to server [mongo-rs-1-svc:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo-rs-1-svc mongo-rs-1-svc:27017]\"}". I tried replacing mongo-rs-x-svc to their internal ip addresses in the url. In this case the above name resolution error disappeared but got another error - {\"name\":\"MongoError\",\"message\":\"failed to connect to server [10.0.170.237:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connection 5 to 10.0.170.237:27017 timed out]\"}

What should I be doing to enable this access successfully?

I understand that I can use the webservice to access this data as intermediary but since my lambda is in VPC, I have to deploy NAT gateways and that would increase the cost. Is there a way to access the webservice using the internal endpoint instead of public url? May be that is another way to get data.

If any of you have a solution for this scenario, please share. I went through many threads that showed up as similar questions or in search results but neither had a solution for this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common confusion with Kubernetes. The `Service` object in Kubernetes is only accessible from inside Kubernetes by default (i.e. when `type: ClusterIP` is set). If you want to be able to access it from outside the cluster you need to edit the service so that it is `type: NodePort` or `type: LoadBalancer`.

I'm not entirely sure, but it sounds like your network setup would allow you to use `type: NodePort` for your `Service` in Kubernetes. That will open a high-numbered port (e.g. 32XXX) on each of the Nodes in your cluster that forwards to your Mongo `Pod(s)`. DNS resolution for the service names (e.g. `mongo-rs-1-svc`) will only work inside the Kubernetes cluster, but by using `NodePort` I think you should be able to address them as `mongodb://ec2-instance-1-ip:32XXX,ec2-instance-2-ip:32XXX,...`.

Comment: would this still allow me to keep the mongo deployment private? I don't want that to be internet facing.

Comment: Without seeing your AWS setup to be sure I don't know. :(

Answer (score 0):

Coreyphobrien's answer is correct. Subsequently you were asking for how to keep the exposure private. For that I want to add some information:

You need to make the Lambdas part of your VPC that your cluster is in. For this you use the `--vpc-config` parameter when creating the lambdas or updating. This will create a virtual network interface in the VPC that allows the Lambda access. For Details see [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html).

After that you should be able to set the AWS security group for your instances so that the NodePort will only be accessible from another security group that is used for your Lambdas network interface.

This [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/) discusses an example in more detail.

Comment: ok, will try that out along with what Coreypobrien suggested.